# Overwrite over a file and delete old model's object if the file exists

Tags: django, django-file-upload

I have made something to overwrite a file already uploaded with :

```
class OverwriteStorage(FileSystemStorage):
def get_available_name(self, name):
    if self.exists(name):
        os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, name))
    return name
```

But my file is in a model :

```
class Work (models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(storage=OverwriteStorage(), upload_to=path)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='work_list')
```

And the new upload makes a new enter, so I have :

- A model without file (that bug when I ask file.size..)
- My new model

How can I remove my model when my file is deleted?

I have tried to change again FileSystemStorage process but I can't use any argument (said in doc and tested for hours ;)), I have tried to change save process too, but I didn't succeed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution :

```
for work in groupwork : #It is the list of work associate with my group
    try :
       path = work.file.path.lstrip(SITE_ROOT+'/'+MEDIA_ROOT+'/').rstrip(request.FILES['file'].name)
       deletedwork = groupwork.get(file=path+request.FILES['file'].name)
       deletedwork.delete()
    except:
       pass
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check before continuing to troubleshoot:

- Have you set the MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in the settings.py file?
- Check this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/) for more info on Managing files
- I would take advantage of Django's [built-in file storage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/#storage-objects) rather than building something from scratch

Comment: MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL are ok

Comment: I am trying to do smallest changes, I am ok :D